# Relations between events and $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading the basic concepts of [outcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outcome_(probability)), [event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory)) and [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) on Wikipedia, in order to figure out why the notion of $\sigma$-algebra is used in the definition of the set of events $\mathcal{F}$ of a probability space.

In particular, I was wondering why we may want to exclude some sets of outcomes to be events, which is strictly related on the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ over the sample space $\Omega$ (every time we choose $\mathcal{F} \subsetneq 2^\Omega$ we are excluding some sets of outcomes).

The [outcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outcome_(probability)) page on Wikipedia says:

> Typically, when the sample space is finite, any subset of the sample
>   space is an event (i.e. all elements of the power set of the sample
>   space are defined as events). However, this approach does not work
>   well in cases where the sample space is uncountably infinite (most
>   notably when the outcome must be some real number). So, when defining
>   a probability space it is possible, and often necessary, to exclude
>   certain subsets of the sample space from being events.

I miss a simple example to clarify this claim.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example you are looking for is not simple. The short, and slightly loose, answer is that there is no meaningful way to define a probability measure without restricting it to a strict subset of $2^\Omega$ when $\Omega$ is uncountable.

Comment: Are you saying that we cannot define an *uncountable* additivity property for a measure?

Comment: Well, you *can*, but it turns out that you then can’t have other desirable properties for your measure. (Translation-invariance of the Lebesgue measure on [0,1] is one of them, iirc.) More generally, there are just sets that you can’t coherently assign a measure to. See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set